# How to make \begin{gather} work inside ExSheets' \begin{solution}?

Tags: equations, exsheets

My minimal (not-)working example is as follow. It works only if I comment out the `\begin{gather}` and `\end{gather}` lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings          = block-subtitle ,
  subtitle-format   = \sc ,
  counter-within    = {chapter} , % Contar dentro dos capítulos.
  counter-format    = ch.qu[1] , % Formato 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.
  label-format      = ch.qu[1] , % Formato 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.
  headings-format   = \bfseries ,
  question/pre-hook = \vspace{1ex} ,
  question/post-hook = \vspace{1ex} ,
  question/pre-body-hook = {\vspace{1ex} \mdframed[innermargin=+1cm,outermargin=+1cm]},
  question/post-body-hook=\endmdframed ,
  solution/pre-hook = \vspace{1ex} \mdframed ,
  solution/post-hook = \vspace{1ex} \endmdframed ,
  solution/pre-body-hook = \newline \vspace{1ex} ,
  solution/print    = false ,
  solution/headings = inline
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{question}[subtitle = Erro da área de um retângulo]
 Calcule a área de um retângulo de lados \SI{3.4(2)}{\meter} e \SI{6.2(3)}{\meter}, com o erro correspondente.
 \vspace{5\baselineskip}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{gather}
  \SI{3.4(2)}{\meter} $\times$ \SI{6.2(3)}{\meter} \\
 $ = \left[ \right.$
                    ( \SI{3.4}{}$\times$\SI{6.2}{} )
              $\pm$ ( \SI{3.4}{}$\times$\SI{0.3}{} )
              $\pm$ ( \SI{0.2}{}$\times$\SI{3.4}{} )
              $\pm$ ( \SI{0.2}{}$\times$\SI{0.3}{} )
    $\left. \right]$ \si{\square\meter} \\
 $ = \left[ \right.$
                    ( \SI{21.08}{} )
              $\pm$ ( \SI{1.74}{} )
    $\left. \right]$ \si{\square\meter} \\
 $ = $ \SI{21.08(174)}{\square\meter} \\
 $ = $ \SI{2.108(174)e1}{\square\meter} \\
\end{gather}
\end{solution}

\section*{Soluções dos exercícios}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `gather` environment switches into math mode, so you don't need any of the dollar signs in your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the `gather` environment to run without error outside of the `solution` environment it will also work inside.

- remove all `$` inside `gather` – the contents of a `gather` environment is already in mathmode.
- maybe change `\SI{...}{}` into `\num{...}`
- remove the last `\\` after the last line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings          = block-subtitle ,
  subtitle-format   = \scshape , % USE \scshape INSTEAD OF \sc
  counter-within    = {chapter} , % Contar dentro dos capítulos.
  counter-format    = ch.qu[1] , % Formato 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.
%  label-format      = ch.qu[1] , % <= THIS IS NOT WHAT THIS OPTION IS MEANT FOR!
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{question}[subtitle = Erro da área de um retângulo]
  Calcule a área de um retângulo de lados \SI{3.4(2)}{\meter} e
  \SI{6.2(3)}{\meter}, com o erro correspondente.
 \vspace{5\baselineskip}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{gather}
  \SI{3.4(2)}{\meter} \times \SI{6.2(3)}{\meter} \\
  = \bigl[
    ( \num{3.4} \times \num{6.2} )
    \pm ( \num{3.4} \times \num{0.3} )
    \pm ( \num{0.2} \times \num{3.4} )
    \pm ( \num{0.2} \times \num{0.3} )
    \bigr] \si{\square\meter} \\
  = \bigl[
    ( \num{21.08} )
    \pm ( \num{1.74} )
    \bigr] \si{\square\meter} \\
  =  \SI{21.08(174)}{\square\meter} \\
  =  \SI{2.108(174)e1}{\square\meter}
\end{gather}
\end{solution}

\section*{Soluções dos exercícios}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\end{document}
```

Comment: that first sentence says everything!  +1

Comment: @barbarabeeton :)